# Where can I find more Brood War scenarios?

Tags: house-rules, variants, starcraft

The Brood War expansion of Starcraft introduces the idea of the Scenario Game Mode, which basically comprises a pregenerated galaxy setup with special victory conditions.  Often, playing scenarios provides a more enjoyable (or at least quicker) alternative to playing the normal game.

Unfortunately, the rulebook for the expansion only provides four Scenarios, each with its own particular requirements for number of players.  This puts a significant limit on my options.

Designing my own scenarios is of course a possibility, but due to the time and effort involved, and the inescapable fact that some other avid gamer out there has inevitably done it already, I pose the following question:

**Does there exist, somewhere on this wide vast internet of an Internet we call home, any  collection of further Scenarios which can be used to augment the playing experience?**  Ideally these should be at least somewhat balanced and play-tested, of course, but I'm desperate enough to play anything really.

Other than a few posts on [the BGG forums](http://boardgamegeek.com/forum/1188/starcraft-the-board-game/variants), randomly interspersed among what is a clear majority of non-Scenario variants and house rules, my own searching has come up with naught.

Comment: This question would probably be more apropos at the Gaming site, here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RSid This is the Starcraft board game; they named the board game expansion Brood War, too.

Comment: @VolcanoLotus O.o Fair, my bad. Didn't realize there was a boardgame.

Comment: @RSid No problem; mostly just commented to make sure it doesn't get migrated :) You should give the game a shot! It's getting a little hard to find, and was pricey to start with, but it's one of the best games I've played. Definitely not just a license cash-in. I'd also be interested in more scenarios; I don't believe there are many out there, though. My impression is that most people play the free-for-all "main" mode (which, admittedly, is really fun), and therefore there hasn't been much development by fans. I could be wrong, though...

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the answer is no. After talking with some hardcore Starcraft Board Game people, and a FFG crew member, I have come to the conclusion that noone (as of yet) have made a collection or site with Starcraft scenarios.

They really hoped for more scenarios, but most fans called that the possibilities were too limited.

I was able to find a few scenarios on this lovely list, but it's not exacly a collection.

If you are feeling creative, Im sure the community would love a site about this.

[BoardGameGeek : StarCraft Brood Wars scenarios, variations and maps](http://boardgamegeek.com/forum/1188/starcraft-the-board-game/variants)

Answer (score 0):

## I'm extremely late to the party but

There are some fan made scenarios out there, Uncle Phil on tabletop simulator made some here's the [link](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197976851323/myworkshopfiles/?appid=286160&p=1) to his workship items (he made all the existing scenarios and created 3 more and he did fix the broken links he shared on steam) you can always play on TTS with the mod already done or can arrange it with the real board game.